# Search the node using keyword

Tags: 7, nodes, search, tokens

I have created a text box with button to search the node which has the key word given in text box. Is there any possible to search the node in Drupal 7 with custom search button and textbox which is in tpl file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not include search box generated by custom search module into views, but you can add exposed filter into views to implement search functionality in the views.

To implement search functionality in the views

- Add "field" in the filter and choose "Contains" from the operator list
- Exposed field in the filer

It will display a search box for that field in the views and work nicely for searching. Moreover, you can enhance its display by using views tpl and control where to display this views block.

Comment: **Important:**, remember to re-index the site in `/admin/config/search/settings`, otherwise it won't find it.

Comment: how to re-index

Comment: yourwebsite.com`/admin/config/search/settings`

Comment: instead of search I have search and metadata

Comment: 'Contains' in filter are not in list

Comment: Add "field" in the filter and choose "Contains" from the operator list.can you please explain